# unattended-upgrade does not run because it thinks PC is on battery power

Tags: 20.04, unattended-upgrades

Unattended upgrades are not run on my machine:

```
$ sudo unattended-upgrade --dry-run -v
System is on battery power, stopping
```

This is a desktop computer connected to AC power. It does not have a battery. Ubuntu 20.04.

If I set `Unattended-Upgrade::OnlyOnACPower "false";` in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades` then the updates run. However, this is a workaround, and does not address the problem of why unattended upgrade thinks PC is on battery. How do I fix it properly, without setting `OnlyOnACPower "false"`?

Comment: It's your BIOS and motherboard. Some manufacturers use laptop chips in a desktop case, and let the BIOS handle the discrepancies. Ubuntu cannot fix it.

Comment: I see, is there a setting in the BIOS I can change? I'm using MSI b450 Tomahawk Max II motherboard.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `unattended-upgrade`, it runs `on_ac_power`. If it returns 1, then it is reporting that you are on battery power. Unfortunately, this is a bug. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/powermgmt-base/+bug/1980991

Setting `OnlyOnACPower` to `false` will work around this until they fix it.